# Can anyone help me understand this Python array access syntax?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am looking into this numba example:

https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/examples.html

There is a section where part of an array is loaded into another:

```
sA[tx, ty] = A[x, ty + i * TPB]
```

I see that sA is a 2d array of size 16x16. I know I can access 2d array positions with sA[i][j], but this syntax using a comma inside the [] I don really understand.

What is that doing?

Comment: In `numpy` you **generally shouldn't be using `sA[i][j]`** to access/modify multidimensional arrays, instead, you should be using the multi-dimensional indexing it provides.... Anyway, `sA[i, j]` is indexing with `i` into the first dimension, and `j` into the second dimension... you should probably read [the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Comment: If you use `sA[i][j]` you will instantiate a subsetted array `sA[i]`, which is going to be inefficient.

Comment: Because `sA[i][j]` first creates a new array object  (a view though), `sA[i]`, **then** it indexes into that using `[j]`, this is *particularly problematic* when using assignment.

Comment: It is worth noting that the indexing `sA[tx, ty]` is not actually some extension to the language just for NumPy - it is actually a tuple and could be written equivalently `sA[(tx, ty)]`

Comment: Thanks guys. If you want to move this info into an answer I can accept it.